# How do you programmatically enable a payment method?

Tags: commerce

I have enabled the payment method module I want to use.  I am using Authorize.net.

However, by default it is disabled in the Payment methods listing.

In my module, I want to enable the payment method module for use when my module is installed.

Comment: Why do it through code? Is the goal to selectively enable auth.net payments?

Comment: no, the goal is not to selectively enable auth.net payments.  I will be providing several sites with the same functionality, but I don't want the end user to have to configure the payment methods.  I want to have a module that does this configuration for them and this includes enabling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume this is for Drupal Commerce?
Payment methods are set and enabled by Rules.
I would create a custom module that will make a condition for the Rule, based on a variable that is set elsewhere (as in a custom Admin UI for the site).

Answer (score 3):

Just update the rules_config entity.

```
$config = rules_config_load('name_of_your_rules_config');
$config->active = 1;
$config->save();
```

If you are not sure what the name of your rules config entity is run:

```
$configs = entity_load('rules_config');
foreach($configs as $config) {
  dpm($config, $config->name);
}
```

This will list all rule config entities that you have.